# JavaScript: Filter out keys from array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

**This is what my current object looks like.**
My question is how to parse this object such that it will return the expected output (without index 0,1,2...) I want a Javascript array of objects, without the key value.

```
 "contacts": {
  "0": {
    "firstName": "James",
    "lastName": "April",
    "emails": [
      {
        "emailType": "WORK",
        "address": ""
      },
      {
        "emailType": "PERSONAL",
        "address": ""
      }
    ],
    "relationship": "boyfriend",
    "phones": [
      {
        "phoneType": "HOME",
        "phoneNumber": "(456) 888-9999"
      },
      {
        "phoneType": "CELL",
        "phoneNumber": "(789) 123-4567"
      },
    ],
    "callSequence": 0,
    "note": null
  },
  "1": {
    "firstName": "Joe",
    "lastName": "Kimmel",
    "emails": [
      {
        "emailType": "WORK",
        "address": ""
      },
      {
        "emailType": "PERSONAL",
        "address": ""
      }
    ],
    "relationship": "ex-husband",
    "phones": [
      {
        "phoneType": "HOME",
        "phoneNumber": ""
      },
      {
        "phoneType": "CELL",
        "phoneNumber": "(111) 111-1111"
      },
      {
        "phoneType": "WORK",
        "phoneNumber": ""
      }
    ],
    "callSequence": 0,
    "note": null
  },
  "2": {
    "firstName": "Test",
    "lastName": "",
    "emails": [
      {
        "emailType": "WORK",
        "address": "test@gmail.com"
      },
      {
        "emailType": "PERSONAL",
        "address": "test2@gmail.com"
      }
    ],
    "relationship": "BROTHER-IN-LAW",
    "phones": [
      {
        "phoneType": "HOME",
        "phoneNumber": ""
      },
      {
        "phoneType": "CELL",
        "phoneNumber": ""
      },
      {
        "phoneType": "WORK",
        "phoneNumber": ""
      }
    ],
    "callSequence": 0
  }
}
```

}

**Expected Result**
Wihout the indexes 0,1,2 and should be inside an array. So I want the output as array of objects

```
   "contacts": [{
   {
    "firstName": "James",
    "lastName": "April",
    "emails": [
      {
        "emailType": "WORK",
        "address": ""
      },
      {
        "emailType": "PERSONAL",
        "address": ""
      }
    ],
    "relationship": "boyfriend",
    "phones": [
      {
        "phoneType": "HOME",
        "phoneNumber": "(456) 888-9999"
      },
      {
        "phoneType": "CELL",
        "phoneNumber": "(789) 123-4567"
      },
    ],
    "callSequence": 0,
    "note": null
  },
   {
    "firstName": "Joe",
    "lastName": "Kimmel",
    "emails": [
      {
        "emailType": "WORK",
        "address": ""
      },
      {
        "emailType": "PERSONAL",
        "address": ""
      }
    ],
    "relationship": "ex-husband",
    "phones": [
      {
        "phoneType": "HOME",
        "phoneNumber": ""
      },
      {
        "phoneType": "CELL",
        "phoneNumber": "(111) 111-1111"
      },
      {
        "phoneType": "WORK",
        "phoneNumber": ""
      }
    ],
    "callSequence": 0,
    "note": null
  }]
```

Comment: Where's the data coming from? Assuming it's AJAX, are you not able to change it server-side?

Comment: Note that your array of objects will also have key values, because that's how arrays work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Object.values to get the array you're after.

```
const newObject = {contacts: Object.values(oldObject.contacts)};
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `Object.values` for contacts property

```js
let data =  {"contacts": {
  "0": {
    "firstName": "James",
    "lastName": "April",
    "emails": [
      {
        "emailType": "WORK",
        "address": ""
      },
      {
        "emailType": "PERSONAL",
        "address": ""
      }
    ],
    "relationship": "boyfriend",
    "phones": [
      {
        "phoneType": "HOME",
        "phoneNumber": "(456) 888-9999"
      },
      {
        "phoneType": "CELL",
        "phoneNumber": "(789) 123-4567"
      },
    ],
    "callSequence": 0,
    "note": null
  },
  "1": {
    "firstName": "Joe",
    "lastName": "Kimmel",
    "emails": [
      {
        "emailType": "WORK",
        "address": ""
      },
      {
        "emailType": "PERSONAL",
        "address": ""
      }
    ],
    "relationship": "ex-husband",
    "phones": [
      {
        "phoneType": "HOME",
        "phoneNumber": ""
      },
      {
        "phoneType": "CELL",
        "phoneNumber": "(111) 111-1111"
      },
      {
        "phoneType": "WORK",
        "phoneNumber": ""
      }
    ],
    "callSequence": 0,
    "note": null
  },
  "2": {
    "firstName": "Test",
    "lastName": "",
    "emails": [
      {
        "emailType": "WORK",
        "address": "test@gmail.com"
      },
      {
        "emailType": "PERSONAL",
        "address": "test2@gmail.com"
      }
    ],
    "relationship": "BROTHER-IN-LAW",
    "phones": [
      {
        "phoneType": "HOME",
        "phoneNumber": ""
      },
      {
        "phoneType": "CELL",
        "phoneNumber": ""
      },
      {
        "phoneType": "WORK",
        "phoneNumber": ""
      }
    ],
    "callSequence": 0
  }
}
}
data.contacts = Object.values(data.contacts);
console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property values. In this case, the object to be passed is `contacts` from the original data.

```js
var data = { "contacts": { "0": { "firstName": "James", "lastName": "April", "emails": [ { "emailType": "WORK", "address": "" }, { "emailType": "PERSONAL", "address": "" } ], "relationship": "boyfriend", "phones": [ { "phoneType": "HOME", "phoneNumber": "(456) 888-9999" }, { "phoneType": "CELL", "phoneNumber": "(789) 123-4567" }, ], "callSequence": 0, "note": null }, "1": { "firstName": "Joe", "lastName": "Kimmel", "emails": [ { "emailType": "WORK", "address": "" }, { "emailType": "PERSONAL", "address": "" } ], "relationship": "ex-husband", "phones": [ { "phoneType": "HOME", "phoneNumber": "" }, { "phoneType": "CELL", "phoneNumber": "(111) 111-1111" }, { "phoneType": "WORK", "phoneNumber": "" } ], "callSequence": 0, "note": null }, "2": { "firstName": "Test", "lastName": "", "emails": [ { "emailType": "WORK", "address": "test@gmail.com" }, { "emailType": "PERSONAL", "address": "test2@gmail.com" } ], "relationship": "BROTHER-IN-LAW", "phones": [ { "phoneType": "HOME", "phoneNumber": "" }, { "phoneType": "CELL", "phoneNumber": "" }, { "phoneType": "WORK", "phoneNumber": "" } ], "callSequence": 0 } } };

data = { contacts:  Object.values(data.contacts) }
console.log(data)
```